# Add payload in Ember deleteRecord

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a requirement to include remarks from user in the payload whenever he tries to delete an item. So far, I have this:

```
let remarks = this.get('remarks');
let id = this.get('itemID');

this.store.findRecord('item', id).then(function (selectedItem) {

    // TODO - DELETE doesn't accept payload in body?

    selectedItem.destroyRecord({remarks:remarks}).then(function(response){

        Ember.debug('delete successful:'+JSON.stringify(response));

        Ember.$('#confirmDelete').modal('hide');
        Ember.$('#remarks').val('');

        context.set('successful', true);
        context.set('message', context.get('i18n').t('success.role.delete'));                        

    }).catch(function(error){
        Ember.debug('delete failed:'+JSON.stringify(error));

        Ember.$('#confirmDelete').modal('hide');
        Ember.$('#remarks').val('');

        context.send('showErrors', error);
    });
});
```

It doesn't work. So does setting the remarks value in the model like:

```
...
this.store.findRecord('item', id).then(function (selectedItem) {

    selectedItem.set('remarks', remarks);

    selectedItem.destroyRecord().then(function(response){
...
```

I am trying to override the `deleteRecord` but I don't know where to start or how to do it.

Anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I could think of is to customize your adapter/serializer. A few workaround-suggestions: What about first updating the item with your remarks? Or adding a header (in adapter)? What about not realy deleting that record but setting a deleted flag (since you might want to save that remark somewhere)?

Comment: @jeff, thanks for the ideas. I am currently constrained by our backend API. Can't change them now. I am looking at customizing the adapter but I don't know how to pass the remarks from controller to the deleteRecord function I overrode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily achieve this kind of behaviour by extending your application adapter with the following mixin:

```js
/* app/mixins/delete-with-playload.js */

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  deleteRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
    var id = snapshot.id;
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.modelName);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, snapshot);

    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'deleteRecord'), "DELETE", {
      data
    });
  }
});
```

Then just add it to your application adapter

```js
/* app/adapters/application.js */

import RestAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/rest';
import DeleteWithPayloadMixin from '../mixins/delete-with-payload';
export default RestAdapter.extend(DeleteWithPayloadMixin);
```

This will result a payload identical to the payload of `PUT` method, meaning a payload of the form:

```js
{
  "<model-name>": {
    // model's serialized attributes
  }
}
```

Now all you have to do is to set the desired attributes on the record before deleting, and destroy the record.

```js
model.setProperties({
  deleteReason: 'whatever'
});
model.destroyRecord();
/* 
results a DELETE request when requestBody is "{
  "<model-name>": { 
    ... 
    "deleteReason": "whatever"
    ...
  }
}"
*/
```

Comment: Hi @Ramy, just want to understand why did you put the override inside a mixin? Can't it be inside the adapter itself? Anyway, I think I tried to do something like this but got an error which tells me something like I was trying to delete an uncommitted attribute change (because I set the remarks property of the model). Although I wasn't able to check if it's really the problem.

Comment: Anyhow, will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: @simplymoody the mixin is for the sake of modularity. For example, if you wish to apply this kind of `DELETE` behaviour only on a subset of your model, you can implement `app/adapters/<model-name>.js` for each model, and extend each of the adapters with this mixin and avoid code duplication.

Comment: @simplymoody I tested it with ember-data@2.4.0 and didn't get any error

Comment: finally, I was able to make it work! Thanks! :) Btw, I ran into the error again `Error: Attempted to handle event ``pushedData`` on <core-webapp@model:role::ember948:null> while in state root.deleted.inFlight.`. Found out that this error was from the `normalizeResponse` function I implemented. I think I was manipulating the payload before the promise was fulfilled. Anyway, will accept your answer. Thank you!